# HTML/PHP Checkbox Foreach Loop

Tags: php, html, css

I'm creating a control panel and having check boxes like the following

The value of $myboxid is the checkbox id, example: cb1 and the name is just the value eg Name of place: London. It grabs this information from my database

```
<input id='".$myboxid."' name='cplace[]' checked type='checkbox' value='".$box."'><label for='".$myboxid."'>".$boxname."</label>
```

What I'm trying to do is check which box is selected out of the multi box selection. I can get which boxes are selected and for that to output the value, my problem is I also need it to tell me which boxes are not selected.
My Form method is POST, my php back end is the following

```
$lname=$_POST['cplace'];
if(isset($_POST['cplace'])) {
    foreach($lname as $place){
        echo $place." CHECKED <BR>";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get this to output the checkbed boxes and the ones which are not selected.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need a list of all the checkboxes so that you know which ones are not currently checked. Ideally, you need a list of all the checkboxes amd whether they were checked or not last time.

Comment: Checkboxes are weird, if the user never checks it, it doesn't get sent, but if they check then uncheck it it does.  You may need to send a list of ids to look for so you can correctly check all the possibilities.

Comment: Isn't it simply that the boxes, other than the boxes you received checked, are unchecked?? Can't you get the list of all possible boxes and you already know which ones are checked and therefore from that it is clear that the rest others are unchecked?

Comment: My input is in a while statement as it grabs all the names and values from a  database and inputs all the data creating all the checkboxes.All the checkboxes are stored in a database but I dont want to run a query every time to check if they were checked last time. @RohitKumar yes I could run a query to get a full list and do a statement to check if the ID exists or not from the database but isn't there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can check the value of the checkbox in the POST array.

Simply print all the checkbox from the db and then check the value

In one line you can do like this

Inside your db loop

```
$isChecked=(in_array($_POST['cplace'], $box)) ? "checked" : "";
echo "<input id='".$myboxid."' name='cplace[]' ".$isChecked." type='checkbox' value='".$box."'><label for='".$myboxid."'>".$boxname."</label>";
```